# Wow these [levels] are tricky!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) has no tag guidance or description, and has nearly 500 questions.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No. This "levels" can apply to many different things, and is very ambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   No. Even if this is related to programming, it doesn't help much at all.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No! It can be levels of a game, levels of a set etc., depending on how the OP views it as.

   Some questions don't even have anything to do with "levels", and are using the tag wrongly.

Let's burn these [levels] shall we?

Comment: There seem to be an awful lot of [tag:r] questions.  Maybe an SME in that area could take a look and see if there's any useful subgroup that could be disambiguated out from the other various meanings.  I don't immediately see one, but it's also well outside my area of expertise.

Comment: @RyanM good catch, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46831313/13629335

Comment: I think probably an [r-levels] tag is in order, and then the rest can go unless someone else finds another trend.  Burnination can include retagging a subset.  Alternately, we could remove everything except the [r-levels] ones and then just have a mod rename the tag.

Comment: For [pandas] some seem to be borrowing the term from [r] which might make a [r-levels] tag overly specific if [pandas] is going to use it as well. There are others in [pandas] which seem to be dealing with index levels in a MultiIndex. In most of those cases this should be re-tagged [multi-index].

Comment: @RyanM the "levels" referred to in R are less particular to the programming language as to the statistical concept of [Design of experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) where different factors have different levels.  Probably want to discuss the [`factors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factors) tag as well. Perhaps both could be merged into [`experimental-design`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design)?

Answer (score 2):

A brief scan of the first dozen questions indicates they nearly all refer to [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) of [factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factors) in an [experimental-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design).  More detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) that I have spent way too many years of my life studying.

These are statistical concepts which aren't specifically programming-related, but it looks like questions tagged as such are in languages which focus on data science applications.

Certainly the tags themselves ought not to exist on their own; I initially thought to propose [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels) and [factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factors) as synonyms of [experimental-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design), but then saw that [factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factors) is intended for integer factoring, and there's a separate [r-factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factors) tag which is supposed to be used.  Which implies [r-levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-levels) might be appropriate, but we need fewer tags, not more.

I still think merging a lot of things into [experimental-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design) is the right way to go.

Comment: I've got quite some R experience, and imo adding questions about levels to r-factors makes total sense (a level is always a property of a factor, r-levels sounds redundant) but merging them into experimental-design doesn't make sense at all (factors can be used for a variety of purposes, some of which are related to experimental design, but some aren't. For example, a factor can be a nice way to represent which categories should be present in a plot)